# Creating multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, calculated-columns

```
SELECT 
    SUM([FinalECL]) + SUM([EarlyCorrections]) AS [CollectiveProvisions],
    CASE
        WHEN [Currency] = 'EUR' THEN [CollectiveProvisions]
        WHEN [Currency] = 'DKK' THEN [CollectiveProvisions]*0.13
        WHEN [Currency] = 'NOK' THEN [CollectiveProvisions]*0.1
        ELSE [CollectiveProvisions]*0.094
    END AS [CollProv_New]
FROM
    CollectiveProvision_Q22022
WHERE 
    [MONTH] IN ('202204')
```

But when I run the query, it shows this error message:

> Invalid column name

How could I fix this bug? `[FinalECL]` and `[EarlyCorrections]` are existing columns in the `CollectiveProvision_Q22022` table.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but it appears to be a working one:

```
SELECT SUM(CollProv_New) FROM (

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Currency = 'EUR' THEN CollectiveProvisions*1.0
    WHEN Currency = 'DKK' THEN CollectiveProvisions*0.13
    WHEN Currency = 'NOK' THEN CollectiveProvisions*0.1
    ELSE CollectiveProvisions*0.094
END AS CollProv_New FROM (


SELECT SUM(FinalECL) + SUM(EarlyCorrections) AS CollectiveProvisions, Currency
FROM CollectiveProvision_Q22022
WHERE MONTH in ('202204')
GROUP BY CURRENCY


) as T ) as T2
```

Answer (score 1):

The invalid column is `CollectiveProvisions`. To re-use this calculated column you should create it in a before-statement like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM([CollectiveProvisions]) AS [CollectiveProvisions],
SUM([CollectiveProvisions] * [CurrencyFactor]) AS [CollProv_New]
FROM (
    -- here the before-statement
    SELECT SUM([FinalECL] + [EarlyCorrections]) AS [CollectiveProvisions],
    [Currency],
    CASE
        WHEN [Currency] = 'EUR' THEN 1
        WHEN [Currency] = 'DKK' THEN 0.13
        WHEN [Currency] = 'NOK' THEN 0.1
        ELSE 0.094 END AS [CurrencyFactor]
    FROM CollectiveProvision_Q22022
    WHERE [MONTH] in ('202204')
    GROUP BY [Currency])
```